# How to teach PhpStorm generate fully qualified class name corresponded to project's structure and vice verse

Tags: php, phpstorm

In my new company didn't use namespaces at all... so fully qualified class name corresponded to PSR-0.

Here is an example. Project structure looks like this...

```
App
  |-Controller
           |-Guest        
                 |-Book.php
```

Inside of the `Book.php` class name should look like this...

**class Controller_Guest_Book.php**

Now I need to create full structure and file name manually

[image: Example]

What I did:

- A point to PhpStorm root folder of the project.
- PhpStorm solves only namespace's problem.
- It generates correct namespaces but unfortunately there is no need.

Is there a way to generate full class name correspond to project's structure and vice verse? Generate project structure depending on full class name?

Comment: Your "Example" link doesn't actually show any screen shot or anything other than ads. When posting questions and including images, you should upload it using the image button in the SO-editor instead. It uses imgur and can be displayed inline in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I fix the image's link. But this service didn't allowed display it inline.

Comment: You can get rid of namespace generation if you unmark your folder as Source folder in `Settings/Preferences | Directories`. The rest -- don't think so ... especially these days when using namespaces in a 100% normal & expected practice (I doubt that devs even ever had a thought on implementing this).

Comment: @LazyOne thanks I know it. I marked folder as root with hope what it help me achive my goal. I'm still searching solution. I hope it is achievable.